# Stopping training in Keras if accuracy is below x at epoch y

Tags: keras

In addition to the basic early stopping features in KERAS, I would like to stop training if the validation accuracy is still below 0.80 at epoch 40.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think an existing callback with such functionality exists, but you can write a custom callback to accomplish this. See the following example, copied from this stackoverflow answer and modified for your specific example:

```
from keras.callbacks import Callback

class TerminateOnBaseline(Callback):
    """
    Callback that terminates training when either acc or val_acc reaches a specified
    baseline after a specified number of epochs
    """
    def __init__(self, monitor='val_accuracy', baseline=0.8, n_epochs=40):
        super(TerminateOnBaseline, self).__init__()
        self.monitor = monitor
        self.baseline = baseline
        self.n_epochs = n_epochs

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        logs = logs or {}
        acc = logs.get(self.monitor)
        if acc is not None:
            if acc < self.baseline and epoch >= self.n_epochs:
                print('Epoch %d: Accuracy has not reached the baseline, terminating training' % (epoch))
                self.model.stop_training = True
```

You can then include this callback when training your model using the `callbacks` argument in the `fit` method.